# MS-Access Timesheet tracking assistance please

Tags: ms-access

First post to the ol' Stackover flow even though you guys have been helping me for a long time via google results. To which I thank you all!

Also my first dive into MS Access ever with minimal experience before hand.

My situation is as thus : We have a company that we buy time clocks from and they log the clock ins and the time worked. We can then go into our account and pull a report with three majorly important bits of information. Employee Name, their clock in location, and the total time a shift was.

I am trying to make it so that I can import this data to Access and have it output a report that I can pass on to the accounting team. I am so close to victory I feel like I can taste it. The problem is I have no clue how to make this blasted software do a running sum (or something like it) with the conditions I have! Let me provide an example:

[Mocked up image in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOrSv.png)

(I hope I pasted that image correctly) The image is a quick mock up of what I already have Access automating for me, but the area in yellow is what I can't get it to do for the life of me! I have two reports I have to make; One report is employee clock ins by location, and the second is the other way around. A list of every employee and every place they clocked in.

I hope to keep learning Access and then VB to improve this over time, but for the time I am looking for something as simple as it needs to be.

Thanks for the insight ahead of time!

Comment: Running sum by group is tricky enough, calculating elapsed time further complicates, especially when period crosses midnight. Really need date portion to deal with that. Sometimes running sum is easiest to calculate on report using textbox RunningSum property.

Comment: Thanks! I will see where that takes me. If you have suggestions for another route to take I will gladly listen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from the picture that SHIFT_TOTAL is a misformatted count of hours worked in a shift.  First SHIFT_TOTAL needs to be correctly formatted then you can calculate a running sum in the query itself or in the report using the running sum.  for an example in a report see here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4
I'll show the in query solution.

[image]

```
'we use two calculated fields

'HoursWorked is just formatting SHIFT_TOTAL

HoursWorked: CDbl(Replace(Replace(Replace([Table2].[SHIFT_TOTAL],"AM",""),"PM",""),":",""))/10000

'Inside a query calculated functions don't exist so for the running sum we DSUM 'a repeat of the hours worked calculation .  Watch out for ' ' around string variables  

RUNNING_SUM: DSum('CDbl(Replace(Replace(Replace([Table2].[SHIFT_TOTAL],"AM",""),"PM",""),":",""))/10000',"Table2","ID <= " & [ID] & " AND EMP_NAME = '" & [EMP_NAME] & "' AND INLOCATION = '" & [INLOCATION] & "'")
```

Comment: Are you AccessDB Jesus? I think that once I set all the variables to match this is doing EXACTLY what I needed. You may have actually inspired me to get some books like Access for Dummies and start learning more with this. I've been having that frustrated "Techie is challenged" fun with it so far, but the deadline to get this right was creeping up on me. Again, new to Stackoverflow posting so if there is a way to email you a taco or something please tell me! <3

Comment: actually my learning came from much pain and I take far longer than I will ever admit solving stack overflow questions.  Glad you liked the answer and keep at it.